# How do I put a docker container in an error state?

Tags: docker

I'd love a consistent way to drop a docker container into an error state to do some testing around container errors.

I was hopeful when I saw `bantl23/error` on the docker hub, but it happily starts with no error.

Comment: see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8294

Comment: What kind of error state?

Comment: Well do a docker inspect and delete some things referred there in the filesystem, sure you will break it sometime

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez docker's pretty rock solid for recovering from this kind of thing. I was impressed after trying several ideas.

Comment: Hehe well it is a good thing after all

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of a container that you can cause to fail on demand from outside - [R0MANARMY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164966/r0manarmy)'s point is valid though - Docker monitors the process it starts, and if the process exits then the container goes to the `Exited` status, there isn't really a concept of an error state.

Having said that, if you want to test an `Exited` container then the image you mentioned does work, but it's limited - it runs, waits for 10 seconds and then exits:

```
docker run -d bantl23/error
```

If you want something you can control from the outside, I've put a very simple image together for that - [sixeyed/bad-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/sixeyed/bad-server/). It's an HTTP server that you can force into an error state by hitting `http://ip:8080/err`:

```
> docker run -d -p 80:8080 sixeyed/bad-server
8b4bd7ffd96d543c9b51c7709267894d2bc75daa99ea80250d5e7846f98a6526                                                                         
> docker logs -f 8b4
+ exec app
Listening on port 8080                                                                                                        
Responding to path:
test                                                                                 
err!
> docker ps --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
8b4bd7ffd96d        sixeyed/bad-server   "go-wrapper run"    37 seconds ago      Exited (1) 10 seconds ago                         fervent_hawking
```

While the `logs` were running, I hit `http://localhost/test` and then `http://localhost/err` - which caused the container to exit.